# Is there a limit on the amout of data while using image src as base64 strings?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, base64

I am trying to use base64 data string for images and for some weird reason some of the images are not getting rendered on IE8 or IE7 (I don't care about IE6), however they work fine on IE9 and FF (I tested on FF 3.5.0 and above). Is there any limit on the amount of data supported by IE as base64 data strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is 32 KiB according to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: No wonder they don't work in IE7 as it's not supported and since they are around 40 KB it exceeds the max limit supported by IE8. One more reason not to like IE anymore. Thanks @Robie.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

> Internet Explorer 8: Microsoft has
> limited its support to certain
> "non-navigable" content for security
> reasons, including concerns that
> JavaScript  embedded in a data URI may
> not be interpretable by script filters
> such as those used by web-based email
> clients. Data URIs must be smaller
> than 32 KiB.
>
> Internet Explorer through version 7 (approximately 27% of the market as of July 2010), lacks support.